# SimpleModal Popup - Closing popup with other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, simplemodal

I need help to close a SimpleModal popup when clicking a button 'submit'. The page where this button is is an iframe within the popup SimpleModal. the code of the page below.

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="mc-form">

            <div id="mc">
                <p>Por favor desenha a forma no quadro abaixo ou gere uma nova forma: (<a onclick="window.location.reload()" href="#" title="Clique para Gerar um novo Captcha">Gerar</a>)</p>
                <canvas id="mc-canvas">
                    Your browser doesnt support the canvas element - please visit in a modern browser.
                </canvas>
                <input type="hidden" id="mc-action" value="posclick.php"/>
            </div>
            <p><input disabled="disabled" autocomplete="false" type="submit" value="Seguir"></p>


        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to just remove the form from the dom when the form is submitted

```
$("#mc-form").submit(function() {

    $(this).remove();

});
```